# How to display input value on condition in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm want to display multiple inputs through a loop in react with a condition:
If manual is true then i can manually change every input;
if manual is false then the input should devide a given number (24) to 12 (or the amount of inputs) input values.

I'm basically having trouble setting a condition to have my input values displayed when manual is off and when manual is true to have my input values taken off or sohw their own values.

```
const [baseline, setBaseline] = useState('');
const [budget, setBudget] = useState([]);
const [input, setInput] = useState('')
const [manual, setManual] = useState(false);  

                                
<form className="inputs">
  {Array.from({length: 12}, (item, mon) => {
    return new Date(0, mon).toLocaleString('en-US', {month: 
     'short'})}).map((mon,ind)=>(
         <div key={ind} className="month">
            <label>{`${mon} ${new Date().getFullYear().toString().slice(-2)}`} </label>
             <input  
               type="text" 
               onChange={handleInput} 
               value={manual ? do nothing : 24/2} <---- how do i make this work?
               ref={inputRef} 
               index={ind} 
               disabled={manual ? false : true}
              />
                                                
          </div>
         ))}
 </form>
```

Comment: what exactly do you want? Is is not so clear. Please be specific and as clear as you can be.

Comment: @decpk i updated my question but long story short > how do i set value based on condition?

Comment: `value` is not an action that you passing as a prop to child component. Either it will contain some value or not. You can use `value={manual ? "" : 24/2}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator as:

```
value={manual ? "" : 24 / 2}
```

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

what It will do is it will only set the value as `24/2` i.e `12` if `manual` is `true` else it will set empty string`""`

```
<input
  type="text"
  onChange={handleInput}
  value={manual ? "" : 24 / 2}
  ref={inputRef}
  index={ind}
  disabled={manual ? false : true}
/>
```

Comment: The problem is that you cannot input anything if value=""

Comment: Then you have to implement `onChange` function